# i am trying to filter recyclerview with search view but it is not working

Tags: java, android

I've followed tutorials but each has separate logic, I tried this code which having problem that list is not replaced with new list,while I have written code of replacing list of search results with older list,remember my `recycler-view` is working perfectly the only problem is search view is not working

**here is my code**

```
adapter class
```

```
public class AdlistAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdlistAdapter.AdViewHolder> {
    private Context mCtx;
    private List<DetailsofAd> productList;

    public AdlistAdapter(Context mCtx, List<DetailsofAd> productList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.productList = productList;
    }
//note my list is perfectly working
//here is filter method
   public void setFilter(ArrayList<DetailsofAd> newList){
        productList=new ArrayList<>();
        productList.addAll(newList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

**main class**

```
public class SearchDishes extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener{
    List<DetailsofAd> productList;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;

   android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_dishes);
        toolbar=(android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolBar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recylcermain);
        empty=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        productList = new ArrayList<>();   }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar,menu);
        MenuItem menuItem=menu.findItem(R.id.search);
        android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchView=(android.support.v7.widget.SearchView)menuItem.getActionView();
        return true;
    }
   @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        newText=newText.toLowerCase();
        ArrayList<DetailsofAd> newList=new ArrayList<>();
        for (DetailsofAd detailsofAd : newList)
        {
            String title=detailsofAd.getTitle().toLowerCase();
            if (title.contains(newText))
            {
                newList.add(detailsofAd);
            }
        }
        AdlistAdapter adapter = new AdlistAdapter(SearchDishes.this, newList);
        adapter.setFilter(newList);

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not create new list in filter method . just assign by this.productList . 
please change your code by this .

```
public class AdlistAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdlistAdapter.AdViewHolder> {
    private Context mCtx;
    private List<DetailsofAd> productList;

    public AdlistAdapter(Context mCtx, List<DetailsofAd> productList) {
        this.mCtx = mCtx;
        this.productList = productList;
    }
//note my list is perfectly working
//here is filter method
   public void setFilter(ArrayList<DetailsofAd> newList){
        this.productList = newList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: @muizzalvi i could not understand why you are creating newList in **onQueryTextChange**  method . 
you are filtering empty list . 
please filter with non empty list .

Comment: as i mentioned i just followed tutorial, my onQueryTextChange is not even displaying a Toast , i think there is an issue with SearchView versions..please provide link of latest and simple tutorial for this if you have,thanks

Comment: see [this](http://myhexaville.com/2017/11/08/android-searchview-with-recyclerview/)